# Excel 2010, sum individual cells rather than a range in a row using a sumif function

Tags: excel-2010

With Excel 2010, I am trying to sum individual cells rather than a range in a row using a `sumif` function. Example: the formula `= sumif(c2,"<>",(k2+n2+q2+t2))` does not work.  Must this be a range and not individual cells?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the data you're working with it is a bit difficult to answer your question.

`sumif` requires a single cell reference or range of cells.  You can try breaking the formula down into multiple `sumif` formulas:

```
=sum(sumif(c2,"<>",k2),sumif(c2,"<>",n2),sumif(c2,"<>",q2),sumif(c2,"<>",t2))
```